# mongo c++ driver 3.2/3.x for windows.string corrupted

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

[image: bsoncxx::to_json(doc)]

if I use the debug mode, when Execute to the "bsoncxx::to_json(doc)", it will be corrupted and pop up the following window

[image: string corrupted misktake]

But if I use the release mode,no misktake occurred

Comment: Please re-post this without using screen shots. Instead, copy and paste the code and the error message as text into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can't mix C++ libraries built against the different Debug and Release runtime libraries in the same process. If you want to be able to build both Debug and Release versions of your program, you will need to build both Debug and Release versions of the C++ driver, installed to different locations.